# How to send the json data to server in a format from extjs Json Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, jsonstore

I have an application which will get the json response like below when the page loads.

```
{
{"level2List":[{id:'id1', name:'sample'},....]},
{"level3List":[{id:'id1', name:'sample'},....]},
{"level4List":[{id:'id1', name:'sample'},....]}}
```

So i am taking all the records inside the root elements like "level2List", "level3List", level4List etc.. By using those records I am creating an editable grid. When the user edits any record i am calling store.sync method. Then it is sending the json only for the edited records to the back-end servers. like

```
[{id:'id1', name:'sample'},....]
```

But I need to send the json data in the same format in which i am getting on page load. I mean I need to send the edited records with the root elements with which they belong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your model instances have knowledge of to which "root elements" they belong, you could achieve this by creating a custom writer. For example, if you extend Ext.data.writer.Json, and create your own writeRecords() method within it, you could dynamically define the root that you want to send through.

```
writeRecords: function(request, data) {
    var root = this.root; // HERE IS WHERE YOU COULD DEFINE YOUR ROOT
    if (this.allowSingle && data.length == 1) {
        // convert to single object format
        data = data[0];
    }
    if (this.encode) {
        if (root) {
        // sending as a param, need to encode
            request.params[root] = Ext.encode(data);
        } else {
            //<debug>
            Ext.Error.raise('Must specify a root when using encode');
            //</debug>
        }
    } else {
        // send as jsonData
        request.jsonData = request.jsonData || {};
        if (root) {
            request.jsonData[root] = data;
        } else {
            request.jsonData = data;
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

The, you simply need to use the custom writer on your proxy.